# Piecewise defined polynomial time complexity?

Tags: time-complexity

As part of my research, I have recently written an algorithm for mining medical data. We are looking to potentially publish some of the data we collected however I would like to describe the algorithm I used in detail.

I was really curious about the algorithm so I recently programmed a dummy data generator and tested the algorithm. To my surprise, a simple plot of overall time vs. N (number of input arrays) yielded an almost perfect polynomial fit below N = 100000 and a secondary almost perfect polynomial fit at N >= 100000.

I am curious about potential explanations for this behavior and would be interested in learning more.

Comment: My initial guess is [cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache) effects. ​ ​

Comment: I was thinking something along those lines too. It would seem oddly coincidental that a jump in efficiency is seen at N = 100000. The input data is in the form of Pandas DataFrames.

Comment: It's probably an implementation artifact (combined with a cache effect) - not necessarily yours (could be the library's).

Comment: This question is impossible to answer given the given data.

Comment: Depending on how sharp the transition is, another possibility is that your $\hspace{1.47 in}$ complexity is something like ​ N$^2$ + (100000$\cdot$N) . ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: The transition is very sharp. A linear least squares polynomial fitted between in the range(0,10000) yielded a correlation of 0.999 and the same observation was seen for a second fit between the range(100001,200000) which upon further consideration (and reading!) definitely hints at a cache effect. The source of the effect does not matter to me, I'm just happy (for the purposes of the paper) to at least have some explanation.